# How to put div's with 100% width next to each other

Tags: html, css

I want to place any number of div's with 100% width side by side without using margin/padding/left.
So I want to have an overflow-x

```
<div class="pages">
    <div class="page page_1 shown">1</div>
    <div class="page page_2">2</div>
    <div class="page page_3">3</div>
//... much more div's
</div>
```

Do you have any ideas?
Sorry for my very bad english... :/

Comment: If they have a width of 100%, they can't go next to each other, there just isn't space.

Comment: I suppose you don't want to show them all at the same time, but one by one and just have them there ready for display?

Comment: Try this - http://jsfiddle.net/smk7rama/

Comment: @MaryMelody Nice.  Functional and does not use `float` where it isn't needed.

Comment: Are you looking for a html+css solution only or can you use Javascript/jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Contrarily to what the others think, it is possible. You can use the `vw` (viewport width) unit.

http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/90t997aa/

```
body {
    width: 300vw; /* 3x the viewport */
}
.page {
    width: 100vw; /* every page has the width of the viewport */
    float: left;
}
```

Here is the [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units) table.

EDIT: I just realised you could simply set the body width to `100*n %` where `n` is the amount of divs you have. Then set the divs' width to `100/n %`. [Like so](http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/90t997aa/1/). Browser support ought to be better this way, but some browsers might not round off the numbers all too well, causing some pixel differences.

Comment: 'vw units' don't have enough browser support ... not recommendable.

Comment: @henser So, any feature that isn't integrated by all browsers shouldn't be used? Then stop using border-radius, gradients, shadows, canvas, box-sizing, or, heck, transparent PNGs! The browser support isn't THAT bad. Also, I mentioned in my post that not every browser supports it, with a link to an overview. Don't get why this deserves a downvote. It solves the TS' problem, *and* offers an alternative solution.

Comment: Your alternative is a better answer than the original answer. IMO 'vw units' should be the alterantive as it's not fully supported by IE and Safari.